# Unable to install Slurm on PC

Tags: cluster, slurm

I am trying to install slurm on Ubuntu PC. Therefore, I followed the instructions given over [here](https://drtailor.medium.com/how-to-setup-slurm-on-ubuntu-20-04-for-single-node-work-scheduling-6cc909574365)

I did the following  -

1. `sudo apt update -y`
2. `sudo apt install slurmd slurmctld -y`
3. `mkdir sudo /etc/slurm-llnl`
   FYI... I came up with step 3. by myself
4. `sudo chmod 777 /etc/slurm-llnl`

```
sudo cat << EOF > /etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf
ClusterName=localcluster
SlurmctldHost=localhost
MpiDefault=none
ProctrackType=proctrack/linuxproc
ReturnToService=2
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/none
#
# TIMERS
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
MinJobAge=300
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
Waittime=0
# SCHEDULING
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_tres
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
#
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=info
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=info
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=localhost CPUs=12 RealMemory=8000 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=LocalQ Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
EOF
```

6. `sudo systemctl start slurmctld`
7. `sudo systemctl start slurmd`

Now, when I do this -

8. `sudo scontrol update nodename=localhost state=idle`

I get the error -

```
scontrol: error: resolve_ctls_from_dns_srv: res_nsearch error: Unknown host
scontrol: error: fetch_config: DNS SRV lookup failed
scontrol: error: _establish_config_source: failed to fetch config
scontrol: fatal: Could not establish a configuration source
```

**Edit 1** -

I followed the instructions given by Pau. Now, I get the following outputs -

```
(base) thoma@thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H:/$ systemctl status slurmctld
● slurmctld.service - Slurm controller daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmctld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-03-05 05:57:17 CST; 2h 42min ago
       Docs: man:slurmctld(8)
   Main PID: 6509 (slurmctld)
      Tasks: 10
     Memory: 4.3M
        CPU: 2.378s
     CGroup: /system.slice/slurmctld.service
             ├─6509 /usr/sbin/slurmctld -D -s
             └─6517 "slurmctld: slurmscriptd" "" ""

Mar 05 05:58:27 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmctld[6509]: slurmctld: Invalid node state transition requested for node localhost from=INVAL to=IDLE
Mar 05 05:58:27 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmctld[6509]: slurmctld: _slurm_rpc_update_node for localhost: Invalid node state specified
Mar 05 06:00:07 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmctld[6509]: slurmctld: Invalid node state transition requested for node localhost from=INVAL to=IDLE
Mar 05 06:00:07 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmctld[6509]: slurmctld: _slurm_rpc_update_node for localhost: Invalid node state specified
Mar 05 06:01:30 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmctld[6509]: slurmctld: Invalid node state transition requested for node localhost from=INVAL to=RESUME
Mar 05 06:01:30 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmctld[6509]: slurmctld: _slurm_rpc_update_node for localhost: Invalid node state specified
Mar 05 06:02:13 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmctld[6509]: slurmctld: Invalid node state transition requested for node localhost from=INVAL to=RESUME
Mar 05 06:02:13 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmctld[6509]: slurmctld: _slurm_rpc_update_node for localhost: Invalid node state specified
Mar 05 06:02:20 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmctld[6509]: slurmctld: Invalid node state transition requested for node localhost from=INVAL to=IDLE
Mar 05 06:02:20 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmctld[6509]: slurmctld: _slurm_rpc_update_node for localhost: Invalid node state specified
(base) thoma@thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H:/$ systemctl status slurmd
● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-03-05 05:57:17 CST; 2h 42min ago
       Docs: man:slurmd(8)
   Main PID: 6514 (slurmd)
      Tasks: 1
     Memory: 316.0K
        CPU: 22ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/slurmd.service
             └─6514 /usr/sbin/slurmd -D -s

Mar 05 05:57:17 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H systemd[1]: Started Slurm node daemon.
Mar 05 05:57:17 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmd[6514]: slurmd: error: Node configuration differs from hardware: CPUs=12:12(hw) Boards=1:1(hw) SocketsPerBoard=12:1(hw) CoresPerSocket=1:6(hw) ThreadsPerCore>
Mar 05 05:57:17 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmd[6514]: slurmd: slurmd version 21.08.5 started
Mar 05 05:57:17 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmd[6514]: slurmd: slurmd started on Tue, 05 Mar 2024 05:57:17 -0600
Mar 05 05:57:17 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmd[6514]: slurmd: CPUs=12 Boards=1 Sockets=12 Cores=1 Threads=1 Memory=7838 TmpDisk=1252975 Uptime=372 CPUSpecList=(null) FeaturesAvail=(null) FeaturesActive=(>
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

Comment: Hello, what do you get when you do a `systemctl status slurmctld` and `systemctl status slurmd`

Comment: @Marius_Couet I have updated my question with answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you also started the `munge` service?

Make sure to start it as well by using `systemctl` as follows.

```shell
sudo systemctl start munge
sudo systemctl status munge
```

I recommend you follow [this guide](https://medium.com/@pausantanapi2/slurm-single-node-installation-on-ubuntu-22-04-6479e70f7911) I wrote on how to install Slurm in a single node environment for Ubuntu 22.04.

Cheers.

Comment: I followed your instructions. When I came to this step - `(base) thoma@thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H:/$ scontrol update nodename=localhost state=idle`, I got this error - 
`slurm_update error: Invalid user id`

Answer (score 1):

By seeing the systemctl configuration you've provided, I can tell this things:

1- As for **slurmd**, the HW configuration you defined in slurm.conf is not correct. What are the HW specifications of the node this configuration will run on?

```
 (Mar 05 05:57:17 thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H slurmd[6514]: slurmd: error: Node configuration differs from hardware: CPUs=12:12(hw) Boards=1:1(hw) SocketsPerBoard=12:1(hw) CoresPerSocket=1:6(hw) ThreadsPerCore>)
```

According to this output, your values for **SocketsPerBoard** and **CoresPerSocket**, should be **1** and **6** respectively.

2- Regarding **slurmctld**, the initial node status should be **UNKNOWN**, like this.

```
 NodeName=localhost CPUs=12 RealMemory=30517 State=UNKNOWN PartitionName=localhost Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

NOTE: I have seen you have put "**8000**" as your **RealMemory** value. Try using the value "**8192**" instead, as Slurm uses MiB values :)

Try changing these, then **restart** both **slurmd** and **slurmctld** and let me know if that helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure about the hardware configurations. Since this is my personal laptop, can't we configure Slurm to use what's present?

Comment: You can check your computer's memory by running "sudo lshw -c memory" and CPUs by running "sudo lshw -c processor" or running "lscpu". Then, adjust the slurm.conf file accordingly. Adjusting Slurm.conf parameters dynamically is techincally possible by using the Slurm API, but I don't recommend doing that for the hardware info. I would suggest manually setting the hardware parameters. I highly recommend you read this page: https://slurm.schedmd.com/dynamic_nodes.html. Hope this helps!